# Importing in WebStorm a folder with my html-js-files?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am new to WebStorm. I have a simple Backbone project, where I use git for versioning. How do I add this simple project to my WebStorm project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just open your project root folder in WebStorm using **File | Open**: start WebStorm, from **Welcome** screen choose **Open**, open the folder => all needed project files will be auto-generated.
Checking out the project from Git is another option: choose **Check out from Version Control** | **Git** (or **GitHub**), specify the repository URL, and target directory - fresh copy will be checked out into the specified directory